# How can I get a response from the server such as "Upload Successful"

Tags: java, php, android, json

In my App I am uploading Images to my company server

The issue I am struggling with is I want the server to respond with a Upload succesful or something similar after the picture is uploaded, 
At the moment the upload works but I want Succesful/Error response from the server, I am using koush Ion for the upload and nothing I tried is working thus far  and itried googling for something but I can;t find what I am looking for

**Code for Uploading Picture**

```
private void uploadImageToServer() {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=ImageLoader.init().from(selectedPhoto).requestSize(1024, 1024).getBitmap();
            String encodedImage=ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
            Log.d(TAG, encodedImage);
            CheckBox chk=findViewById(R.id.chk1);
            if (chk.isChecked()) {
                Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder();
                builder.scheme("https")
                        .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
                        .appendPath("files-upload-phone-app.asp")
                        .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Category", Item)
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientName", Item2)
                        .appendQueryParameter("NoEmail", "Yes");
                myURL=builder.build().toString();
            } else {
                Uri.Builder builder4=new Uri.Builder();
                builder4.scheme("https")
                        .authority("www.smartpractice.co.za")
                        .appendPath("files-upload-phone-app.asp")
                        .appendQueryParameter("MyForm", "Yes")
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientID", clientId)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Username", email)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Pwd", pwd)
                        .appendQueryParameter("Category", Item)
                        .appendQueryParameter("ClientName", Item2)
                        .appendQueryParameter("NoEmail", "");

                myURL=builder4.build().toString();
            }
            final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(SecondActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Uploading, Please Wait....");
            pd.show();
            File file=new File(selectedPhoto);
            Ion.with(SecondActivity.this)
                    .load(myURL)
                    .uploadProgressDialog(pd)
                    .setMultipartFile("SP-LOG", "image/*", file)


                    .asString()


                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            pd.cancel();


                        }
                    });


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No File Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: In order to do that your server api must return with message that you want to show. Then you can access the result in onCompleted callback and can do something like this result == "SUCCESS" .

Comment: I have been coding for 3 weeks TOTAL,  how do you do that?,  A link would be very much appreciated

Comment: that's your server software which needs to be changed, you can't force server to do what you want from client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your service returns something like this after an successful image upload by calling UploadImage API:

```
{ 
    "message":"Upload successful",
    "status":200
}
```

The above response will be sent by service side API not from android.

```
//Your above business logic for selecting file
Ion.with(SecondActivity.this)
                    .load(myURL)
                    .uploadProgressDialog(pd)
                    .setMultipartFile("SP-LOG", "image/*", file)
                    .asJsonObject()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                            String message = result.getString("message");
                            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();\
                            pd.cancel();


                        }
                    });
```

or incase API only return string like this in response
"Upload successful"

then you can write like this

```
//Your above business logic for selecting file

Ion.with(SecondActivity.this)
                    .load(myURL)
                    .uploadProgressDialog(pd)
                    .setMultipartFile("SP-LOG", "image/*", file)
                    .asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();\
                            pd.cancel();


                        }
                    });
```

I hope this helps if not please feel free to ask!

Comment: Okay I will test and get back to you, Thanks dude

Comment: I am getting cannot resolve error on the getString, any advice?

Comment: Try result.get("message").getAsString();

Comment: Okay That worked But I get NULL pointer on the toast, My responses are in a json array  and looks like this  <code>MyJasonString = ""
    MyJasonString = MyJasonString & "{""failed"": 1,""Errors"": ["
    MyJasonString = MyJasonString & "{""reason"": ""File Size To Large""}"
    MyJasonString = MyJasonString & "]}"
    response.write MyJasonString<code>

Comment: join here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198577/android-kushon-ion

Comment: Thanks man My boss decided to just recode the JSON, Thanks for all the help

Comment: It works perfectly now so thanks to you my app is completed